# How to query the double-tap duration time from Windows UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-cx, c++-winrt

In my Windows UWP app I have a component that reacts on double-taps. I've implemented this by reacting to the `PointerPressed` event of the `CoreIndependentInputSource`. In the event handler I got the following code:

```
if((e->CurrentPoint->Timestamp - _lastTimestamp) < _doubleClickDuration)
{
  Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new DispatchedHandler([this]()
  {
    // Do whatever needs to be done on double-taps
  }));
}

_lastTimestamp = e->CurrentPoint->Timestamp;
```

`_doubleClickDuration` is the variable that defines the duration of the double-tap.

The code works as expected but the problem that I'm facing is that I need to set `_doubleClickDuration` to a "reasonable" value. What is reasonable for one person might not be for another which is why Windows lets you configure the duration of the double-tap in the Control Panel.

There is a [Windows API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime) named `GetDoubleClickTime` that seems to return the value configured in Windows. However, that function is marked as "[desktop apps only]" which means I cannot call that function from a Windows UWP app.

What is the Windows UWP equivalent to that function or how would I figure out what the configured duration time of a double-tap is?

Comment: There's [UISettings.DoubleClickTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.doubleclicktime). I don't know whether there's a setting specifically for touch input.

Comment: Jackpot, that seems to be it. The value returned by it corresponds with the value specified via Control Panel. It seems to be exactly what is stored in the Windows Registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\DoubleClickSpeed" which is a value in milliseconds. If you post this as the answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You already have a project set up to verify the solution, which puts you in a far better position to produce an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments below my question, the double-tap duration of Windows can be accessed via `UISettings`. First, an object of object of that class must be constructed. I do this as a class member using the following line of code:

```
Windows::UI::ViewManagement::UISettings _uiSettings;
```

The double-tap duration, which *I think* is the same as the double-click duration, can be accessed via property `DoubleClickTime` of the `_uiSettings` object. It returns an `unsigned int` that expresses the double-tap duration in milliseconds.

Because the line `e->CurrentPoint->Timestamp` of the code in my question returns the time in microseconds, it is necessary to multiply `DoubleClickTime` with 1000 in order to be able to compare those values.

So, the full code now looks like this:

```
if((e->CurrentPoint->Timestamp - _lastTimestamp) < (_uiSettings.DoubleClickTime * 1000))
{
  Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new DispatchedHandler([this]()
  {
    // Do whatever needs to be done on double-taps
  }));
}

_lastTimestamp = e->CurrentPoint->Timestamp;
```

Changing the double-tap duration in the Mouse Settings of Windows' Control Panel will also change the return value of the `DoubleClickTime` property.

[image: Mouse Settings]

Note that changing the value that way changes the value of `DoubleClickSpeed` in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`. The default value there is 500 (milliseconds).

[image]